# Django how to get model field and send an email?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am newbie and just see the django documentation of sending mail . i want to send an email to the drivers after seeing their details if they are eligible i want them to send an email using thier email address that they submit while registering to my app . please tell me how do i send a email. i had already set the settings.py email host user all the needs of send an email its working on my other app . but not working on this app . how do i get the driver email and send an email from our company employee.

**Views**

```
    def rentacar_carapp_sendmail(request):
        if request.POST:
            try:
                args['driver'] = driver = Driver.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('driver_id'))
                subject = "Please Register Your Car"
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = carapp.get('car_app_driver_id.driver_email')
                join_message = """thankyou  we will contact you later """
                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[to_email], message=join_message,
                        fail_silently=False)

                driver.save()
            except:
                pass
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/mega-admin/rentacar/driver-manager/')
```

**Models**

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "driver"
        verbose_name = "Driver"
        verbose_name_plural = "Drivers"
        ordering = ['driver_firstname', 'driver_lastname']

    driver_firstname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    driver_lastname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    driver_email = models.EmailField(
        blank=False
    )
```

[image: my employe views]

Answer (score 0):

So in your **forms.py,** you have whatever your form is to collect driver information (this is a hypothetical form for the example):

```
from django import forms

class YourFormName(forms.Form):

    driver_firstname = forms.CharField(required=True)
    driver_lastname = forms.CharField(required=True)
    driver_email = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

etc etc

Then, in your **views.py:**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from yourapp.forms import ContactForm

def email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourFormName()
    else:
        form = YourFormName(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            firstname = form.cleaned_data['driver_firstname']
            lastname = form.cleaned_data['driver_lastname']
            try:
                send_mail(firstname, lastname)
            return redirect('your_redirect_url')
    return render(request, {'form': form})
```

This should help you get the appropriate data for your email.

Comment: i have to functions . one ia for model forms and i want to make a function for sending email. How do i get the driver id into my def mail and send email to him . i am uaing model forms